# Xml validation error The value is invalid according to its datatype 'CopyFrom' - The Enumeration constraint failed

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I am trying to validate an Xml file

My xsd schema fragment:

```
<xs:attribute name="PostIndex" use="optional">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>Post Index</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:length value="6"/>
                                <xs:pattern value="\d{0}|\d{6}"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
```

XML file fragment:

```
<Atr1>
<Atr2 Atr="A9F130BE-3974-4698-B9F9-72037BC0E97F" PostIndex="123456" />
<Atr2 Atr3="123" Atr4="11111" />
</Atr1>
```

when I run the validation code, it passes schema validation I have error:

> The 'PostIndex' attribute is invalid - The value '123456' is invalid
>   according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint
>   failed.

Comment: Does it work if you add a non-numerical value, like "string"?  Shouldn't you be using `xs:integer`?

Comment: If add non-numerical value I have another error - attribute is invalid - The value 'qwerty' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed

Comment: \d = [0-9], so you want 0-9, but as a string?

Comment: I have check against your xsd and it validates correctly. Can you thrown in your whole xml and xsd

Comment: Yes, I need string by schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XSD and XML I used, it works fine. So please post your entire XSD and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="computer">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="it-IT">Definizione di un computer</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-US">Definition of a computer</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="PostInt">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:length value="6"/>
           <xs:pattern value="\d{0}|\d{6}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML

```
<computer PostInt="123456" />
```

I used following [online validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UiShzzakpip)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying online validate my xsd and xml - it's valid. I think my validator work incorrect